# How does the compiler know where are static fields allocated?

Tags: c++

Imagine you have a class A with a static field int mstatic.
Imagine if that class has a method mymethod that modifies mstatic. When compiling mymethod, how can the adress of mstatic be known ? I know that in case of non-static fields, a pointer to the calling object (the famous "this") is implicitly passed to the method so it is used to find the adresses, but how do we do for static fields ?

Answer (score 2):

Static fields are allocated similarly to namespace-scope or global variables... there's basically one or two areas (variables needing 0 initialisation may be separated from those needing initial non-0 values) sequentially populated with all such variables in the translation unit.  If the variable's defined in another variable, the address will be patched in during linking or loading.  Note that the addresses are typically effectively hard-coded (fixed address, perhaps from a specific data segment register), unlike stack (which may be stack register relative, but the stack register is modified as functions are called and return, unlike data segment registers which may be set to the same value while the thread is running) or heap hosted variables (where the address is determined during `malloc` or `new`.

Comment: It's no different to finding global static variables, or other functions